# Can data be recovered from a water-fried iphone?

Tags: data-recovery, damage

My daughter has a 5s that was submerged in salt water and then attempted to power-up prior to the phone fully drying out. The phone shows no signs of life even when plugged into a power source and no computer recognizes the device. My question is whether data (specifically information in the Notes file) can be retrieved and, if so, by whom? These data are not backed-up anywhere; they only exist on the phone. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: I've merged this with the canonical "what are the options to recover data when the phone won't boot". Feel free to ask a follow on question to ask where notes might be stored if you need that information. It could be in a backup file in iTunes or iCloud or another device. The guidance on data recovery is probably your best bet if tools like PhoneView won't read the data off the phone when connected to a Mac (or equivalent PC software)